# Unable to get BlobTrigger for my Azure Function to work?

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a Storage Account named invoicestoragebfda and a Container named veninv_dev. My function is supposed to print the name + size of the blob that triggered the function in the log.

**Function.class**

```
    @FunctionName("blobprocessing")
    @StorageAccount("invoicestoragebfda")
    public void blob(
      @BlobTrigger(name = "blob",
                   dataType = "binary",
                   path = "veninv-dev/{name}",
                   connection = "invoicestoragebfda") byte[] content,
      @BindingName("name") String filename,
      final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
      context.getLogger().info("Name: " + filename + " Size: " + content.length + " bytes");
```

**Function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile" : "../veninv_dev-functions-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "com.veninv_dev.veninv.blob",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "blobTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "blob",
    "path" : "veninv-dev/{name}",
    "dataType" : "binary",
    "connection" : "invoicestoragebfda"
  } ]
}
```

However, when I deploy this Function and upload a file to the Container the Function trigger isn't activated. The Storage Account allows access from all networks.

I've been stuck at this for a good while now, but am unable to figure out what my Function.class and Function.json should look like to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is your connection string is null or wrong. You may use storage emulator when you run locally, so you lost a connection with a storage account after deploy your function to Azure.

In portal, you can navigate to **configuration** and check the **app setting**'s value, which named `invoicestoragebfda` in your case. If you don't have this app setting, add one and write the connection string as value.  In my case, the specific app setting name is AzureWebJobsStorage.

[image]

For getting the connection string, go to your storage account, navigate to **Access Key**, copy your connection string under **key1** to **app settings**.

[image]

Any question you can contact me.

Comment: I checked, and the key1 Connection string and AzureWebJobsStorage value are identical.

Comment: I looked at it again, and realized in Function.class connection = "invoicestoragebfda" should be changed to connection = "Storage", as the connection variable refers to the Application Setting (which is named "AzureWebJobsStorage" for me). Everything works fine now!

Comment: And if you think my answer was helpful, please accept it to help more people. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the question and the answer.

Just note that this section is now under "Environment Variables", and not anymore under "Configuration".

"Settings" -> "Environment Variables" -> "App Settings" -> "AzureWebJobsStorage"

[Azure Function App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8nY2.png)

Comment: This is not an answer. You can put this as comment to the questions.

Comment: I tried to add it as a comment, but could not